# MySQL filling out values from other tables

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `vacancy` which looks like so

[image]

`role` `company` `location` each have a table of there own but I would like to get a query together to pull the information from the other tables to fill in `vacancy`

I tried

```
SELECT  r.title, c.company, l.town, l.country, v.term
FROM role r, vacancy v, location l, company c
```

But this gives my 300 rows of the same `title` when i should in fact have 3 rows returning.

**company**
[image: Company]

**role**
[image: role]

**location**
[image: location]

Comment: can you please share their data structure.???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use join to display data from all four tables

```
SELECT v.id, r.title, c.company, l.town, l.country, v.term
FROM  vacancy v
JOIN  location l ON (v.location = l.id)
JOIN   company c ON (v.company = c.id)
JOIN  role r ON (v.role = r.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Beardy, the reason MySQL is showing 300 rows instead of 3 is because it returned all the data from the three tables simultaneously.
Considering the fact that role, company and location are columns containing the primary keys of the aforementioned tables, all you have to do is a `join`.
Also, considering that this table of yours, `vacancy`is the one from which you want to show the data, this is the query you should use (replace the column names with the ones you actually have in your database):

```
SELECT 
vacancy.id as '#',
role.name as 'Role', 
company.name as 'Company',
location.name as 'Location'
FROM
vacancy
LEFT JOIN role on role.ID = vacancy.role
LEFT JOIN company on company.ID = vacancy.company 
LEFT JOIN location on location.ID = vacancy.location
```

EDIT: I was about to submit this answer when Dianuj posted his... So, I decided to give my answer an extra boost before submitting it :D